# One android layout for multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

I would like to have only one android layout for multiple screens that would display the same resolution. For example, if I set the layout for 320dp, I would like it to show the same app on a 640dp screen but have the app sized as if it is on a 320dp screen. The app would be centered in the middle with a 320dp sized outline, and the background would be black essentially. The app would then work similarly in a larger screen but it would be in the center of the screen occupying the same space as it would on a 320dp screen. Would this be feasible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Linear layout and put below code in manifest file

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest you have to wright this code.

```
enter code here

<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

for a layout you have to make ui for all screen. like
 Small
 Normal 
 Large

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use  combination of `LinearLayout`, 
specify `Layout_weight` for every child except for the outermost `Linearlayout`, 
specify `wiegtSum` for all `LinearLayouts`,
and use `Layout_height="xdp"` and `layout_width="0dp"`

Here is some other ways http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html